# Profile Picture Error

Tags: support, user-profile

I've been trying to change my profile picture, it would upload, but it will change back to the default when i reload the page. why is it doing this and how can i get my profile picture to stay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to scroll to the bottom of the page and press the appropriate button to save any changes to your profile.

Comment: This got me a few times as well lol